# Flutter applications for china android users

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Google Play Store is not available in China. How do I publish my flutter android app on China? my client lives in China. They can't access play store. Is that any option for all any china users to access using on their device?

Comment: Why not ask your client what app store they download from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only publish your app to China by uploading your app to the Chinese platform.

Use this site to publish your app in china. https://www.appinchina.co/

Comment: do you know price?

Comment: I did not do this before, but I heard about it.

Comment: Please Check my Edited answer. @user9139407