# Why Flutter App is not working on hong kong china?

Tags: android, flutter

We are facing an issue when we share APK to the client for the flutter application. and the client country is china(hong kong). so is there any additional setting we need to add for the flutter application for the china region.?

When the client opens the application it only shows a black screen with loader.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you made release apk ??

Comment: yes. and try with different devices. and the apk working as expected over here in india.

Comment: have you use localizations in app??

Comment: No. its only contain english language

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56986089/flutter-applications-for-china-android-users check this might help you if worked please let me knoe

Comment: https://github.com/zonble/flutter_open_chinese_convert check this